# Using CSV module (*no pandas*): How to print the rows in a header column?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, data-science

Define the function `getColumn()` below that takes a column name and returns the data in that column as a list of strings to print the items in a header.

My `getColumn(name)` function fails and gives the error message
`unhashable type:list`

```
import csv
from csv import DictReader
from collections import defaultdict

with open('training_set_features.csv') as new_csv_file:
    new_csv_file = csv.DictReader(new_csv_file,fieldnames=headers)
    data = list(new_csv_file)

column_names = list(data[0].keys())
print("List of column names : ", column_names)

# This part of my code is where I am stuck so it is incomplete
def getColumn(name):
    empty_list=[]
    column=dict[column_names]
    for row in rows:
        return

 print(getColumn('doctor_recc_h1n1'))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Actually the error your code produces is `NameError: name 'headers' is not defined`. It's generally best to provide a [mre] when asking question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The will do what's needed using something called a "[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)" which extracts the data for the named column from each row and returns it.

Note that because `getColumn(name)` is only passed one argument, the column name, it is forced it to use the global variable `data`. If would be better to pass it `data` as as a second argument to avoid needing to do that because it's generally best to avoid them as much as possible.

```
import csv

def getColumn(name):
    return [row[name] for row in data]

with open('training_set_features.csv', newline='') as new_csv_file:
    new_csv_file = csv.DictReader(new_csv_file)
    data = list(new_csv_file)

column_names = list(data[0].keys())
print("List of column names : ", column_names)

print(getColumn('doctor_recc_h1n1'))
```